# Change background color on specifiied scroll position

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with something new in Javascript.
I would like to change the background color of an item when the `scrollY` position has reached a specific value; 80 in this case. However, it's not working. Is there something wrong with the logic?

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event){
   var scroll = this.scrollY;
   if scroll.value === '80' {
       document.getElementById="Gegevens".style.background-color="lightblue" } else {}
})
```

Comment: What does you console say.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
It's on the line where the if function starts

Comment: Well there you go. Daniel Knight mentions how to fix it in his comment below.

Comment: Are you sure `80` is a string and isn't a number?

Comment: The condition of an if statement must be wrapped in brackets. i.e. `if(true) {/*do the thing*/}` Also, you don't need an else block if there's nothing in it. Also, keep in mind comparing a number to it's string-version won't work. `80 === '80'` returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your code:

- You need brackets around your `if` condition
- You already have the scroll value so no need for `scroll.value`
- The scroll position will rarely be exactly 80 so you should do greater than or equal to 80
- 80 is returned as a number, not a string (though you can compare it as a string, it doesn't make much sense to)
- The syntax for `getElementById` needs brackets not an equals sign
- You need to use camelCase for `background-color`
- Something I just learnt, you don't need to pass `event` as a parameter when using `this` (not an error but interesting either way)

This is how it should be:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
   const scroll = this.scrollY;
   if (scroll >= 80)
       document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.backgroundColor="lightblue"
})
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is missing brackets

Comment: Yeah idd, but still nothing happening and console is free of errors..